# MapOverlay draw() method optimization

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is my draw method. I have 755 roads and about 10 coordinates on each road. So I need two for loop to draw paths. It is running too slow. Any help on optimizing this code. Maybe I don't have to create some of objects.

```
    Projection projection = mv.getProjection();
    roadList = getRoadList();
    int length = roadList.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Coordinate[] coordinateList = roadList[i].getCoordinateList();
        int numberOfCoordinates = coordinateList.length;
        Path path = new Path();

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfCoordinates - 1; j++) {
            Coordinate coordinateFrom = coordinateList[j];
            Coordinate coordinateTo = coordinateList[j + 1];
            GeoPoint geoPointFrom = coordinateFrom.getGeoPoint();
            GeoPoint geoPointTo = coordinateTo.getGeoPoint();
            Point pointFrom = new Point();
            Point pointTo = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(geoPointFrom, pointFrom);
            projection.toPixels(geoPointTo, pointTo);
            path.moveTo(pointFrom.x, pointFrom.y);
            path.lineTo(pointTo.x, pointTo.y);

            if (!canvas.quickReject(path, EdgeType.BW)) {
                if (j == numberOfCoordinates - 2) {
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                }
            }               
        }           
    }
```

In get methods there is not any calculations. They are just getting some predefined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating the `Paths` outside the `onDraw()` method rather than each time it's called (which could be hundreds of times).  The data doesn't seem to change between calls.  Create them as you get the data and keep them in a Collection of some sort.  Then draw them in `onDraw()`.

Comment: Good suggestion. But don't I need to calculate pixels on each pan and zoom event fire? Or can I catch these events and calculate pixels?

Comment: I comment out everything in second for and just put a draw line method. It is still too slow.

Comment: Mmm.... Good point.  I wasn't thinking in terms of `MapView`.  Usually when I do that I override `Overlay` with custom overlay items or use the built-in `ItemizedOverlay` with `OverlayItem` and have each object determine it's location.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Estimated time of running two for loop: 2 miliseconds. When I move my finger about 20 pixels, draw() method is running 10 times. So total estimated time : 2 seconds. I think I shouldn't draw anything when my finger is on map. I will try to override onTouch() event.